# followupEventInput does not trigger the corresponding intent

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

The followupEventInput does always trigger the 'default fallback intent'. I have no idea why it doesn't trigger the corresponding intent.

Any help would be appreciated!

my code:

```
return {
  "followup_event_input": {
  "name": "example"
  }
}
```

[image: click here to see how I use example event in dialogflow]

Answer (score 0):

Can you share some details on the two input context , also as you are trying to invoke the intent via custom event , you can remove the input context. If you want to keep the input context make sure that the context are alive before hitting the intent.

Also , were are you referencing this from :`return { "followup_event_input": { "name": "example" } }`

You can follow this link to get more idea around custom events :[Custom Events](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/events-custom)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Those two input contexts are alive before hitting the intent. In regards to the return statement, it gets called as a WebhookResponse. The code is something like

Comment: if intent == 'intentX':                                                                                                             return {"followup_event_input": { "name": "example" }} .                                               The intent is matched, but as soon as it wants to execute the return statement, it goes to the fallback intent.

Comment: One more thing is that option.recipe.question intent is the followup intent for another intent. That might be the reason that the event doesn't get triggered.